# Check if two intervals overlap in R

Tags: r, range, intervals

Given values in four columns (FromUp,ToUp,FromDown,ToDown) two of them always define a range (FromUp,ToUp and FromDown,ToDown). How can I test whether the two ranges overlap. It is important to state that the ranges value are not sorted so the "From" value can be higher then the "To" value and the other way round.

Some Example data:

```
FromUp<-c(5,32,1,5,15,1,6,1,5)
ToUp<-c(5,31,3,5,25,3,6,19,1)

FromDown<-c(1,2,8,1,22,2,1,2,6)
ToDown<-c(4,5,10,6,24,4,1,16,2)

ranges<-data.frame(FromUp,ToUp,FromDown,ToDown)
```

So that the result would look like:

```
FromUp ToUp FromDown ToDown   Overlap
      5    5        1      4    FALSE
     32   31        2      5    FALSE
      1    3        8     10    FALSE
      5    5        1      6    TRUE
     15   25       22     24    TRUE
      1    3        2      4    TRUE
      6    6        1      1    FALSE
      1   19        2     16    TRUE
      5    1        6      2    TRUE
```

I tried a view things but did not get it to work especially the thing that the intervals are not "sorted" makes it for my R skills to difficult to figure out a solution. 
I though about finding the min and max values of the pairs of columns(e.g FromUp, ToUp) and than compare them?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @akrun et al., can you please show how `foverlaps()` can be used to solve the question? Maybe I'm mis-understanding the question.

Comment: I have a hard time too seeing how you can use `foverlaps` in this case. As `foverlaps` requires the setting of keys, the order of the respective columns is changed, while this question requires a rowwise comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort them

```
rng = cbind(pmin(ranges[,1], ranges[,2]), pmax(ranges[,1], ranges[,2]),
            pmin(ranges[,3], ranges[,4]), pmax(ranges[,3], ranges[,4]))
```

and write the condition

```
olap = (rng[,1] <= rng[,4]) & (rng[,2] >= rng[,3])
```

In one step this might be

```
(pmin(ranges[,1], ranges[,2]) <= pmax(ranges[,3], ranges[,4])) &
    (pmax(ranges[,1], ranges[,2]) >= pmin(ranges[,3], ranges[,4]))
```

The `foverlap()` function mentioned by others (or [IRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/IRanges)::`findOveralaps()`) would be appropriate if you were looking for overlaps between *any* range, but you're looking for 'parallel' (within-row?) overlaps.

The logic of the solution here is the same as the answer of @Julius, but is 'vectorized' (e.g., 1 call to `pmin()`, rather than `nrow(ranges)` calls to `sort()`) and should be much faster (though using more memory) for longer vectors of possible ranges.

Comment: Yes, that was perhaps not clear enough I`m looking for overlaps within the rows.
It seems like your answer was just what i was looking for and if i understand the code right takes the min and max approach. Great!Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In general:

```
apply(ranges,1,function(x){y<-c(sort(x[1:2]),sort(x[3:4]));max(y[c(1,3)])<=min(y[c(2,4)])})
```

or, in case intervals cannot overlap at just one point (e.g. because they are open):

```
!apply(ranges,1,function(x){y<-sort(x)[1:2];all(y==sort(x[1:2]))|all(y==sort(x[3:4]))})
```